# How to add an image in the people search result?

Tags: 2013, people-search

I want to add an image (icon) before homePhone.

I added this in my code :

```
<img src="image/tel.png">
```

But I have this :

[image]

How to add an image? Where should I create the folder "image" and what is the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your assets folder under Style Library of the site collection or if you're on on-prem put it inside a folder with the _layouts "15" hive.

Comment: Ok and what's the url if I create a folder in Style Library?

Comment: I found, it's : "/Style Library/Images/logo.jpg". Thks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the Display Template and image assets you can also put them in a subfolder in the Master Page Catalog. I find this easier as all the design assets are contained in folders relative to the Display Template in the master page gallery.